# Draw 8 Images on HTML5 Canvas Draggable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm just learn about JavaScript, and I just found how to make draggable image drawn on HTML5 Canvas but It only one image.

So, I want to make 8 images drawn on HTML5 Canvas draggable, **here's my progress :**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
var canvasHeight=canvas.height;
var isDragging=false;


$(function(){
var image1 = document.getElementById('btn');

image1.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(img,0,0,440,300);
        }   
        img.src = event.target.result;

        function handleMouseDown(e){
            canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
            canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
            // set the drag flag
            isDragging=true;
        }

        function handleMouseUp(e){
            canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
            canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
            // clear the drag flag
            isDragging=false;
        }

        function handleMouseOut(e){
            canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
            canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
            // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
            //isDragging=false;
        }

        function handleMouseMove(e){
            canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
            canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
            // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
            if(isDragging){
                context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
                context.drawImage(img,canMouseX-128/2,canMouseY-120/2,440,300);
            }
        }

        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
        $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

        }                       

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
    }
});
```

**This codes only able for one image, I want to put 8 images in one canvas, any solution?** please help me...Thank you

Comment: With your current code, you'll drag the image no matter where on the canvas that you're clicking, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But, it's for one image only, I want to draw 8 images in that canvas, and I can drag each image. Do you have solution for this? @Niddro

Comment: I've run into this problem myself when I was making a jigsaw-puzzle game, I'll write you a possible solution later this evening. If you're unpatient you can have a look at the source code of my puzzle game yourself. I'll be able to explain it later though: http://home.niddro.com/HTML5/puzzle/puzzlegame.html

Comment: Okay sir, I'll wait for your solution as soon as possible, thank you @Niddro

Comment: Oh well, the question has been marked as duplicate ;)  I still made a fiddle that you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/6jbv3spf/ in this one, only the clicked image will be moved and also move to the top of the other images.